# GCM canonical id

Tags: java, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

When having multiple regids for 1 device GCM returns the canonical id error:

```
{"multicast_id":xxxx,"success":2,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":1,"results":[{"message_id":"xxxxx"},{"registration_id":"newest reg ID here","message_id":"xxxxxx"}]}
```

So it shows the newest regid that should be used by GCM but why isn't it showing the regid that you should delete (the old one)? How do I know what the old regid is and which one I should delete from my database?

Comment: how r u keeping your database.r u using device id>?

Comment: 3 columns. One with regid, other one  with app id (used for other matters), and third the type (ios or android)

Comment: the regid is assigned unique according to the app id. Use app id as ur leverage.

Comment: im not saving the device id. Correct me if I'm wrong but thats different than the registration id right?

Comment: @MarkMolina yes, deviceId is different than the registration id. Device Id is stored within your device that makes your device globally unique while the registrationID in this context is the registration id of the Device + Application on GCM server.

Comment: @MarkMolina I think storing device ID will not fix the problem either. Can you please let me know if you find any solution? I am having the same problem.

Comment: @Adil Malik: Check the answers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eran's answer is correct, though I found it still a bit foggy for me. However, thanks to him I found a solution.

Say this is your response:

```
{
   "multicast_id":xxxxx,
   "success":7,
   "failure":0,
   "canonical_ids":2,
   "results":[
      {
         "message_id":"0:xxx%xxxxx"
      },
      {
         "message_id":"0:xxx%xxxxx"
      },
      {
         "registration_id":"MY_REG_ID_1",
         "message_id":"0:xxx%xxxxx"
      },
      {
         "message_id":"0:xxx%xxxxx"
      },
      {
         "message_id":"0:xxx%xxxxx"
      },
      {
         "registration_id":"MY_REG_ID_2",
         "message_id":"0:xxx%xxxxx"
      },
      {
         "message_id":"0:xxx%xxxxx"
      }
   ]
}
```

As you can see 2 of the 7 messages are a duplicate.

This is the way I send messages to the server:

```
$tokenResult = mysql_query("SELECT reg_ids FROM table_with_regids"); //
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($tokenResult)) {

     $registrationIDs[$i] = $row['reg_ids'];
     $i++;
}
```

**from Eran's answer:**

> Since you get a response from Google for each request you send, you
>   should know which Registration IDs were sent to Google in the request
>   that triggered this response. The old Registration ID that you have to
>   delete is the second Registration ID in that request.

This means that index **2** and **5** of the array **$registrationIDs[]** should be replaced with **MY_REG_ID_1** and **MY_REG_ID_2**.

Finally check for double values and remove the exact duplicates. The result should be an array with 5 regids (or directly delete that index from your array instead of replacing with MY_REG_ID_#).

Answer (score 4):

The GCM response you included indicates that you sent a message to two Registration IDs. Both messages were received in the GCM service successfully. Only for the second message you got a canonical Registration ID.

Since you get a response from Google for each request you send, you should know which Registration IDs were sent to Google in the request that triggered this response. The old Registration ID that you have to delete is the second Registration ID in that request.

Comment: I added my own answer with an example. Your answer really helped though. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

//ASSUME gcm_registration_table field
// id || registration_id || user_id || created_at || updated_at


// FIND CANONICAL IDS POSITION
function CanonicalIdPosition($gcm_response)
{
    $c_ids = array();
    foreach ($gcm_response['results'] as $k => $val) {
        if (isset($val['registration_id'])) {
            $c_ids[] = $k;
        }
    }
    if ($c_ids) {
        return $c_ids;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

// Find Duplicate registration Ids from Server Matchind to index position
function DuplicateRegIdFromRegistrationTable($canonical_ids)
{

    DB::query("SELECT registration_id FROM gcm_registration_table");
    $results = DB::fetch_assoc_all();
    $duplicate_reg_val = array();

// Match Position and Find Value
    foreach ($results as $key => $val) {
        if (in_array($key, $canonical_ids)) {
            $duplicate_reg_val[] = $val['registration_id'];
        }
    }

    return $duplicate_reg_val;
}

// update existing Duplicate registration id with New Canonical registration ids
function UpdateDuplicateRegIds($duplicateVal)
{

    foreach ($duplicateVal as $val) {
        $sql = "UPDATE gcm_registration_table SET registration_id = {$val} WHERE registration_id ={$val}";
// Some Yours Code...
    }
}

// Method to send Notification to GCM Server
function SendGcmNotification($registatoin_ids_from_table, $message, $gcm_api_key, $dry_run = false)
{

// Set POST variables
    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
        'data' => $message,
        'dry_run' => $dry_run
    );

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . $gcm_api_key,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

//print_r($headers);
// Open connection
    if (!class_exists('curl_init')) {
        $ch = curl_init();
    } else {
        echo "Class Doesnot Exist";
        exit();
    }


// Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

// Execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    if ($result === FALSE) {

        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
        return false;
    } else {
        return json_decode($result, true);
    }

// Close connection
    curl_close($ch);
}


//This Wont Send Notification to Device but gives you response to remove canonical ids
$gcm_response = SendGcmNotification($registatoin_ids_from_table, $message, $gcm_api_key, $dry_run = true);

$canonical_ids = CanonicalIdPosition($gcm_response);

if ($canonical_ids) {
    $duplicate_ids = DuplicateRegIdFromRegistrationTable($canonical_ids);
    UpdateDuplicateRegIds($duplicate_ids);
}

// Finally Get updated Registration Ids from table and send to GCM Server with
$gcm_response = SendGcmNotification($registatoin_ids_from_table, $message, $gcm_api_key, $dry_run = false);
```

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer since code only answers are not clear.

Comment: Follow steps. It will be clear and also function method explains steps

Comment: It is not clear. People ust don't have XX mins to check answers which can be useless for them after all